# How to clip the black area from PNG image in java

Tags: java, image-processing, graphics2d, image-clipping

I have a png image which contains black and transparency in the black area. I need to draw my other image, and retain the transparency area as is. What are all the possibilities we have in Java using graphic2d [this is the PNG i am reffering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwpfv.png)

Comment: what is that you have done? and where is the problem with the image shown - I dont see nothing

Comment: If you check the png image i have two colors one black area, and other one is transparent so only on the black area i need to draw my image, can you please provide me some clue to solve this...